# I want to use PointPillars in autoware, but how to train the model?

Tags: c++

I want to use PointPillars in autoware, but the resulat of the pretrained model is bad, How can I train my own model?  Or How to find the better model.

Comment: Maybe adding the relevant code to the question help you get the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.